# How to change class of next 3 siblings in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change class of next 3 siblings in this case?
I want to create pagination (3 elements on each page).

```
<button id="leftbutton"><</button>
<ul id="basepattern">
  <li class="baseshown">1</li>
  <li class="baseshown">2</li>
  <li class="baseshown">3</li>
  <li class="basehidden">4</li>
  <li class="basehidden">5</li>
  <li class="basehidden">6</li>
  <li class="basehidden">7</li>
  <li class="basehidden">8</li>
  <li class="basehidden">9</li>
</ul>
<button id="rightbutton">></button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KDyC9/

```
base_nextpage: function() {
   $(".baseshown").addClass("basehidden");
     $(".baseshown").nextAll(".basehidden:lt(3)").addClass("baseshown");
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way to do it, for example to move to the next page:

```
$(".baseshown")
    .toggleClass("baseshown basehidden")  // toggle currently visible elements
    .last().nextAll().slice(0, 3)         // get elements that go into next page
    .toggleClass("baseshown basehidden"); // and toggle those as well
```

Note that this does not take into account what happens when you are already on the last page -- you can detect this by checking the `.length` after `.nextAll()` or some other equivalent.

Comment: Thanks a lot! All genius is simple!!

Answer (score 0):

Here it is for back and forward with limit checking:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {

    var next = $(this).data().dir === 'next' ?        
        Math.min(currentPage + 1, numPages - 1) :
        Math.max(currentPage - 1, 0);

    load(currentPage = next);    
});

var load = function (page) {
    items.removeClass('shown');
    items.slice(page * pageSize, page * pageSize + pageSize).addClass('shown');;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stto3703/44Nn9/